# Create new Array if the Object Key is encountered and push the Value into it

Tags: jquery

I have the following objects...

```
var object1 = {
    TransactionType: 'Service PO',
    Level1: 'Payment Terms',
    Level2: ''
};
var object2 = {
    TransactionType: '',
    Level1: '',
    Level2: 'PT1'
};
var object3 = {
    TransactionType: '',
    Level1: '',
    Level2: 'PT2'
};
var object4 = {
    TransactionType: '',
    Level1: 'Delivery Terms',
    Level2: ''
};
var object5 = {
    TransactionType: '',
    Level1: '',
    Level2: 'DT1'
};
var object6 = {
    TransactionType: '',
    Level1: '',
    Level2: 'DT2'
};
var object7 = {
    TransactionType: 'Material PO',
    Level1: 'Transportation Terms',
    Level2: ''
};
```

Now the real scenario is,

1. First check the TransactionType, if it contains any value like in our case it has 'Service PO', then create an array and start pushing the objects into that array (in our case it will go till object6).
2. But as object7 contains TransactionType, it wont insert into the array instead create a new array and repeat the same process.
3. so basically the 1st array will contain 6 objects and the second array will contain only 1 object.

   Note, there could be 'n' number of objects, so the only thing to keep in mind is 'TransactionType'. As soon as you encounter that the next 'TransactionType' contains any value, stop pushing the objects into the array.
       How to achieve this using jQuery or Javascript. any help would be highly appreciated.. 
       Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? This reads like you're trying to get people to complete  an assignment for you.

Comment: I tried this... but unfortunately its not creating the new array instead it pushes in the same array. https://jsfiddle.net/cuzp94pc/5/
the object7 should be in the new array but unfortunately its in the same. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If anyone can help me, that would be very grateful... Thanks

Comment: Rory McCrossan you can check my fiddle what i have tried... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it as per my requirement.whenever the 'TransactionType' is encountered, i Just kept on saving the data in object key which is 'TermsCategories'.
        [FIDDLE HERE][1]
        [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/hwuzbbz8/

```
Note the above solution was according to my requirement. you can customize it accordingly whenever such situation arises in your project. Sorry for the identation. thanks
```